# How do I send variables from Express to a dynamic page

Tags: node.js, express, templates, mean-stack, mean.io

I've recently switched from XAMPP/LAMP stack to MEAN stack and oh dear, these new things are amazing but I can't wrap my head around this.

In a LAMP stack, if you want to display some variable (like your username from a Database or some dynamic variable like that) you'd do something like this:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $some_var; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

and that's it. At the start of the file, you can pass the data from a Database to the variable and that would be it.

I don't understand how you achieve this in a MEAN stack.

Do I have to use a Template engine like EJS/Pug? If I understand it, I'd do back-end in the same file that Express is (like for example, selecting data from databases) and then I'd do something like this:

**app.js**

```
app.set("views", "./views");
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.render("index", {message:"Hi"});
});
```

Is that how you send data from server→client in a production/deploy environment? Is there a more practical solution to it? Given that pug code is way too different from HTML (for example). Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a MEAN stack, you would use Express as the backend API and pass JSON data to the frontend, which could be Angular, React, Vue, etc.

For templating with Express, [this](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) should get you started. Let us know if this helps :)

Comment: [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) is a guide to get you started with EJS :)

Comment: Thanks! I was taking a look at it and it helped me. Also, another question, how would you use Angular in a MEAN stack?

Comment: You would build out the Angular app separately, then consume data from the Express API. The same site provides this [guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular) as well. Hope this helps.